# Angular datetime binding timezone conversion

Tags: angularjs, datetime, datetimepicker

I have an app that get's a datetime via a json object from a rest service.  It comes back like this:

```
2014-03-30T08:00:00
```

I bind to it and pass it through the date filter, it looks like it puts it into local time.

```
{{ mytime.begin | date:'dd-MMMM-yyyy hh:mm a Z' }}
30-March-2014 08:00 AM -0400
```

But if I bind to it from a date time picker (every one I've tried so far), it subtracts the offset but still thinks it's utc.  Here's an example from the angular-strap timepicker

```
<input type="text" size="8" class="form-control" ng-model="mytime.begin" time-format="hh:mm a Z" data-autoclose="1" placeholder="Time" bs-timepicker> 
04:00 AM -0400
```

But if I set the time through the timepicker it binds the other way correctly.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: so you want to show local time zone ?

Comment: Yes, my concern is that in ng-model it applies the offset but still shows it as -0400.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so here is what I have discovered.  You know what they say about assumptions ;).  So MySQL is storing the dates as UTC, but does not bother to be specific about that with a trailing 'Z' or '+0000'.  When that date is returned and parsed it is handled differently in different cases.

Angular Filter assumes ambiguous dates are in local time.

```
{{ mytime.begin | date:'dd-MMMM-yyyy hh:mm a Z' }}
30-March-2014 08:00 AM -0400
```

The javascript Date.parse function will assume ambiguous dates are in UTC.  Angular Strap has it's own date parsing helper, I assume it's doing the same thing.

```
<input type="text" size="8" class="form-control" ng-model="mytime.begin" time-format="hh:mm a Z" data-autoclose="1" placeholder="Time" bs-timepicker> 
04:00 AM -0400
```

To add to the confusion, think my app server is doing the same thing but converting it to localtime.  Anyway by being explicit about the time zone the issue goes away.